# display nested array in json file with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, nested

I'm trying to figure out how to reach and display nested arrays in an external JSON-file.
 In the example below "color" is an array with exactly two different colors. In real I would like this number to shift between one and more colors, but to get an output I have used exactly two colors.

Right now: If one searches for example "bl" the program will return all names that start with "bl", but only colors with index 0. Never index 1.

Wanted result: The user should be able to search for colors, regardless of where in the "color"-array the color is.

I have searched here on SO and elsewhere, but I haven't been able to transfer that info to my own project. The closest to a solution I've come was with restructuring. This way I could get the color of index 0 and the second color as an object when I console.log it. When I tried with for-loop, I only got the index of 0 even when I changed the 0 to I.

My JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "firstName": "bonnie",
            "lastName": "parker",
            "_comment": "HERE ARE THE COLORS",
            "color": ["pink", "purple"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/bonnie.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "firstName": "stephanie",
            "lastName": "st.Clair",
            "color": ["yellow", "orange"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/stephanie.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "al",
            "lastName": "capone",
            "color": ["green", "black"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/al.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "dillinger",
            "color": ["blue", "red"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/john.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "firstName": "ma",
            "lastName": "baker",
            "color": ["green", "white"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/ma.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "clyde",
            "lastName": "barrow",
            "color": ["yellow", "gray"],
             "image":{
                "url":"/images/clyde.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "carlo",
            "lastName": "gambino",
            "color": ["pink", "blue"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/carlo.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "jesse",
            "lastName": "james",
            "color": ["gray", "purple"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/jesse.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "firstName": "benjamin 'bugsy'",
            "lastName": "siegel",
            "color": ["blue", "purple"],
            "image":{
                "url":"/images/bugsy.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]    
}
```

My JS

```
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.button');
const searchText = document.querySelector('.search');
const matchDOM = document.querySelector('.matchOutput');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-search');

/** Get the search-item */
const getItem = async searchText => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/items.json')
        const data = await res.json();
        let product = data.items;
        let matches = product.filter(item => {
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
            return item.firstName.match(regex) || item.lastName.match(regex)
                 || item.gender.match(regex) || item.color[0].match(regex)  /** HERE IS THE PROBLEM **/
        });
        if (searchText.length === 0) {
            matches = [];
            matchDOM.innerHTML = '';
        }
        itemOutput(matches);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

/** Display the search-item */
const itemOutput = matches => {
    const myHtml = matches.map(match => `
    <div class="search-group">
         <img src=${match.image.url} alt="product" />
        <div class="text-info">
            <h2>Name: ${match.firstName}</h2>
            <h3>LastName: ${match.lastName}</h3>
            <h4>${match.gender}</h4>
        </div>
        <h4 class="colors">${match.color}</h4>
    </div>
    `)
    myHtml.sort();
    matchDOM.innerHTML = myHtml;
}

/** Search via Enter-click */
searchText.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    searchBtn.click();
  }
});

/** Search via Button-click */
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getItem(searchText.value)
})

/** Clear search */
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    matchDOM.innerHTML = '';
})
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, your problem is, that in your code, the search term gets only checked against the *first* color entry, not *all color* entries. If I'm right, the solution would be to change the last term in you OR-chain in line 15 from

...  `|| item.color[0].match(regex)`

to

...  `|| item.color.filter(c => c.match(regex)).length !== 0`

### explanation

Your last expression only checks if the first color matches the regex. The replacement above filters all colours by the result of the match and simply checks if one or more colors actually matched by checking the returned array's length.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item.color[0].match(regex)`, apply the regex to the string representation instead: `(""+item.color).match(colorregex)`.
For matching the colors, use specific regex to ensure matching the colors if i>0 accondingly:

```
const colorregex = new RegExp(`.*(^|,)${searchText}.*`, 'gi');
```

Comment: the regex contained a marker so the string only matches when string representation starts with searchstring. I edited my answer accordingly